# Hibernate Exception: identifier of an instance of x was altered

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my test code:

```
        Employee emp = new Employee();

        emp.setUsername("test");
        emp.setPassword("test");
        sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        log.debug("SessionFactory created");
        session = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        log.debug("Saving Employee");
        System.out.println(emp);
        session.save(emp);
        session.flush();

        if(!tx.wasCommitted())
        {
            tx.commit();
            log.debug("Employee saved");
        }
```

This is my Employee Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee 
{
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="emp_id_sq", strategy="generator.EmployeeIdGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator="emp_id_sq")
@Column(name = "EMP_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String username;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
private String password;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
private Collection<Timecard> timecards;
```

Error I receive: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of models.Employee was altered from 24 to 24

I have no idea why I'm getting the error, but it happens when I try to commit the save.

Comment: try remove flush() and just only commit(). probably flush() generate new @Id and commit() thrown error.

Comment: Mmm try to put `type` property in annotation , [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2350621) you have the same issue

Comment: Perhaps you should also enable SQL logging: sf.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

Comment: My guess is that the problem is cause by this unknown EmployeeIdGenerator.

Comment: It did not like my `@GenericGenerator(name="emp_id_sq", strategy="generator.EmployeeIdGenerator")`, I removed it and used `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` instead and it works perfectly.